# Istio 127.0.0.6

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I use istio:

```
istioctl version
client version: 1.11.2
control plane version: 1.11.2
data plane version: none
```

k8s:

```
kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.21.5
Server Version: v1.21.5
```

When I'm deploying my app (nginx+app) nginx healthcheck has fail.

```
 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.6
```

I understand why, but can't understand what is 127.0.0.6 in istio.
I found only 1 links on github (https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/29603). My app has service and declare port. But still can't figure it out how to running healthcheck on 127.0.0.1 and what is 127.0.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 2 years I found an answer=)

I actually didn't correctly understand reason of this 127.0.0.6 behavior. The reason why this address I saw in log it's address apears when traffic doesn't go outside from pod. In my case it was because nginx-container made a healthcheck to app-container and they both was in one pod. That's why traffic was still in the pod.
And it is logic of istio works.

You can read more about it here https://jimmysong.io/en/blog/sidecar-injection-iptables-and-traffic-routing/